# Customized jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker. I want to personalize this widget, for example when is Christmas or Easter holidays i want the background of the entire widget to display a snow / rabbit image, or something relevant to this specific holiday. E.g. December = christmas background and 24 December = Santa Clause.

Comment: Is a monthly based option enough (etc. december = christmas backgroud) or should it be date dependent?

Comment: He wrote it was the widget? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { 
       if(month===[whatever]) {
          // add a css class to set background image
       }
    }
});
```